# Footer is pulled to left when screen size gets smaller

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my website responsive, but when screen size gets smaller `<footer>` is pulled to the left. Here is the photo

[image: footer is pulled to the left even though it has justify content center]

`<p>`tag above `<footer>` stays in the center.

When screen size is bigger 250px footer gets to its position.

Here is the code in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d4mwnt9q/1/

Comment: Please show the media query(s) in your css.

Comment: You're not sharing all of your CSS - please share more info for us to help.

Comment: @sigil this all the code in css I used to style footer

Comment: @Rob Moll added them

Comment: Can you provide HTML code you use?
I suspect that you don't have defined class for the `<footer>` element and you use `.footer` class as a selector in CSS.

Comment: @urosevic <footer class="footer"> it is there, just named it as it is

Comment: @Bakhodir CSS code you have provided in question should work. You have some error in HTML or CSS code that you have not shown to us. Please provide complete code (HTML and CSS) in jsfiddle.net so we can help you.

Comment: @urosevic added jsfiddle, but actually footer is not visible there

Comment: @urosevic one more bug, on 551th pixel button "send" breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form input in the mobile media query is creating problems. It's knocking the text off, you need to change it from:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
 .form>input {
  width: 28rem;
 }
}
```

To 100% in the mobile version like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
   .form>input {
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Then center the p text in the footer like so

```
.footer p {
font-size: 2.4rem;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 7rem;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped, also what's wrong with the button, it slides to the next line when screen size reaches 550 pixels, I mean it is not positioning itself in the center

Answer (score 0):

@Bakhodir Button breaks to 2nd row because low max-width media query.
This should work:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 570px) {
  .form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 48rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 2rem;

  }

  .form > input {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .form > button {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}
```

Check out https://jsfiddle.net/urosevic/ruhg9djq/14/